# Handlebars.js issue regarding the helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have created the helper to generate the "li" code as below:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("REQUEST_LI", function(id){
                                    var LI = "";
                $.each(APP.que_random_ids, function(i, v){
                        if( v.subject == id ){
                            LI = LI + "<li><input type='button' value='"+v.index+"'/></li>";    
                        }
                });

                return LI;
    });
```

The output is generated properly. But in the template it shows the "li" tags.

```
</li><li><input type='button' value='74'/></li><li><input type='button' value='75'/></li><li><input type='button' value='76'/></li><li><input type='button' value='77'/></li><li><input type='button' value='78'/></li><li><input type='button' value='79'/></li><li><input type='button' value='80'/></li><li><input type='button' value='81'/></li><li><input type='button' value='82'/></li><li><input type='button' value='83'/></li><li><input type='button' value='84'/></li><li><input type='button' value='85'/></li><li><input type='button' value='86'/></li><li><input type='button' value='87'/></li><li><input type='button' value='88'/></li><li><input type='button' value='89'/></li>
```

I am calling the helper on click of button. If you have any ideas please share.

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that "IN the template" the html output is displayed as it is. Means the "<li></li>".

Comment: Ok, I get it. Could you add to your question how you actually render it? And the template? Not sure I can help, but that might be useful.

Comment: See, first time the view has rendered, hence we have load the html of that view too. Now there is one option which update the small portion of view. I want helper which update that section. When some one request for that means "click on button" again the same view render but now the model data is different. As this view template use the helper which returns the bunch of "li tag". But when these returned "li tag" tagged in html of template these are treat as code. Meaning to say the "return li" tags get printed. If possible then please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars HTML-encodes things that are in `{{...}}` by default. So if you say:

```
{{REQUEST_LI x}}
```

then your helper will produce the desired HTML as a string and then Handlebars will HTML-encode it (i.e. `<` becomes `&lt;`, ...).

There are two ways around this:

1. The helper can return a `Handlebars.SafeString`: `return new Handlebars.SafeString(LI)` instead of `return LI`.
2. You can leave it up to the template and use `{{{...}}}` to skip the encoding step: `{{{REQUEST_LI x}}}` instead of `{{REQUEST_LI x}}`.

I'd probably go with option **1**.

A quick demo of how triple-staches and SafeStrings work: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZN2ej/

Answer (score 0):

He is absolutely correct with his explanation. One more way to skip this encoding is to '#' . Try this -

```
{{#REQUEST_LI x}}{{/REQUEST_LI}}
```

[This is how default helpers like if, each are written.]